# Escaping the dot in groovy expression binding from java

Tags: java, groovy

How do you escape . (dot) in evaluating the bindings in a GroovyShell?
It seems the evaluator is not able to handle the .

```
import groovy.lang.GroovyShell;
import groovy.lang.Binding; 
public class BindingSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String expression = "sample.name == ben ||  sample.name == mark || sample.name == trae";

        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.setVariable("sample.name", "ben");
        GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);
        Object result = shell.evaluate(expression);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}

Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: sample for class: Script1
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:518)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:556)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:527)
    at templates.postprocess.BindingSample.main(BindingSample.java:23)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, and probably shouldn't try to, "escape" the dot in variable identifiers. That's because when the script references `sample.name`, Groovy will try to read the `name` property of an object in a variable named `sample`.

If you really (*really really*) need to use that identifier, then perhaps you should use `getProperty` directly, although this shouldn't be done in normal script code... The following worked:

```
String expression = "getProperty('sample.name') == 'ben' ||  getProperty('sample.name') == 'mark' || getProperty('sample.name') == 'trae'";
```

Also note that your comparison doesn't quote string literals, and that's another reason for failures in that expression.

You have yet another alternative, that of using a map:

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put("name", "ben");
binding.setVariable("sample", m);
```

And this should allow you to run your expression as it was (with literals in quotes, of course)

Comment: In the alternative of using a map.... do I still need to add the getProperty?  I did not add the getProperty in my expression and I am encountering the same error.

Comment: @MarkEstrada No. You would be able to use your original expression, as mentioned (just making sure you quote string literals: 'ben', 'mark', 'trae'...)